# How the assignment statement in an if statement serves as a condition?

Tags: c, if-statement, boolean, assignment-operator

```
if ((vnd = (struct diam_vnd_t *)g_hash_table_lookup(vendors,vend))) {...}
```

Can you tell me why it is an assignment but not a boolean expression in the brackets ? And in what situation this assignment can be considered "true" or "false" ?

Comment: Any halfway modern compiler will warn about that for good reasons

Comment: @Olaf Even after using `((..))`?

Comment: @SouravGhosh: Hmm, I really did not notice them. Ok, I change to "should". Verified with gcc: It even suggest the parentheses to avoid the warning (and they work). Heck, that should require an explicit comparison to suppress the warning, nothing less visible. Thanks for informing me.

Comment: The marked duplicate is not an duplicate, because the linked question answers about the usage and this question asks about the behavior. I'm reopening this. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quoting `C11`, chapter §6.5.16, *Assignment operators* (*emphasis mine*)

> An assignment operator stores a value in the object designated by the left operand. **An
>   assignment expression has the value of the left operand after the assignment,<sup>111)</sup> but is not
>   an lvalue.**

So, first the assignment will happen, and then, the value that has been assigned will be used as the conditional statement in `if`.

So, in case of

```
if (p = 0 )
```

will evaluate to FALSE and

```
if (p = 5)
```

will be TRUE.

Comment: thanks, this is exactly what i need, i will accept it.

Answer (score 0):

C considers anything non-zero to be `true`, and anything 0 to be false.

This assignment's value is equal to the value it assigns to `vnd`, in this case, a `struct diam_vnd_t *`. The if statement checks whether or not `vnd` is `NULL` after the assignment.

This would be equivalent to:

```
vnd = (struct diam_vnd_t *)g_hash_table_lookup(vendors,vend);
if (vnd) {...}
```

Comment: C very well has a boolean type. And in a condition, any expression is converted to a boolean result (of type `int`, though).

Comment: The `bool` type is just an `unsigned int`. Fundamentally, the language deals with "zero" and "non-zero" as booleans, rather than `true`/`false` atoms.

Comment: No, `_Bool` is a distinct unsigned integer type with the values `0` and `1` `bool` is a macro in `stdbool.h` which maps to `_Bool`. It is **not** `unsigned int`. Note: This is standard C, not some homebrew `typedef`! About the "true"/"false" interpretation: Try `_Bool b = 4;` or `printf("%d", (bool)5);`. Note that boolean logic does not define how "true"/"false" have to be represented. Often they are by `0`/`1`, because that simplifies mathematical operations. See Wikipedia.

Comment: It would be better to read the C standard directly (specifically 6.2.5p2 and p6 e.g.) instead of a second/third source. Maybne you will find some other new features since the last 17 years. You might also find that `NULL` is a macro with a _null pointer constant_, not a specific value. A pointer variable can only be a _null pointer_. And that is not required to have a binary representation of all-zeros. Still, such a null pointer has to evaluate "false".

Answer (score 0):

The logical operator for "is equal to" is `==`

When you're saying `vnd = (struct...` you are assigning everything after `=` to the variable `vnd`. If you want a true or false you need to use `==`

Answer (score 0):

Assignment is always done with one equal sign. `=`

```
int i;
i = 0; //assignment
```

This assigns 0 to an integer called `i`.

The same thing happens with your if statement. Whether or not it is in an if statement is irrelevant.

```
(vnd = (struct diam_vnd_t *)g_hash_table_lookup(vendors,vend))
```

To do a boolean expression, you need to use `==`.

```
(vnd == (struct diam_vnd_t *)g_hash_table_lookup(vendors,vend))
```

This will return true or false based on the comparison of the 2 items

Comment: `int i = 0;` is **not** an assignment.

Comment: @Olaf  `int i; //declaration`, `i = 0; //assignment` <-- Like that?

Comment: These are different things!

Comment: @Olaf Right, I am aware of that, I just wanted to confirm thats what you were referring to. I suppose I should have seperated the two.